# LSTM Regularizers

Tags: python, keras, lstm, regularized

I wish to use an L1 or L2 regularizer on my layers in my stacked LSTM. However, I can't tell which one of `kernel_regularizer=None, recurrent_regularizer=None, bias_regularizer=None` I should select and modify. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For example , for l2 regularizer

```
from keras.regularizers import l2


Bidirectional(LSTM(LSTM_unit, kernel_regularizer=l2(0.05),recurrent_regularizer=l2(0.05), return_sequences=True, dropout=dropout))(x)
```